# Neo smartpen for input

Tags: input-devices

Is there a way to use the superb Neo Smartpen (or Moleskine+) as an input device (let's say for Inkscape)?

The pen offers Bluetooth connection and there's an open-source SDK in GitHub.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. Are you even able to use yours with ubuntu? I wasn't aware of it being able to sync to a linux system, and so sold mine when I moved to linux.

Comment: No, unfortunately not ... I've bought a wacom intuos tablet